# Want to introduce disable into ng-options in a directive

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to make hidden items to be disabled (and preferably in red stricken font). Our current directive has the following and stops working when I try to add disable part:

```html
 <select name="deeplinkDropdown" id="deeplinkDropdown"
            class="form-control dropdown deeplinkDropdown"
            ng-disabled="disable"
            data-ng-model="dropdownModel.key"
            data-ng-options="item.key as item.text disable when item.hidden for item in itemList | filter:ngOptionFilter"
            data-ng-change="modelChanged(dropdownModel.key)">
        <option value="">{{noneSelectedLabel}}</option>
    </select>
```

The item may not have item.hidden property at all although some lists do have it. (I have this directive used multiple times in a form).

I tried to figure out syntax looking at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions and it seems like this variation should work, but it does not. Do you see how should I fix this directive? For now I'll remove the disable part.

Comment: You can remove ng-disabled from select and what is the value of item.hidden?

Comment: item.hidden is false for 99% of the items.

Comment: Did you remove ng-disabled?

Comment: No. I removed my addition of 'disable' part in ng-options, but the directive stopped working for me for some reason. On the first load I now don't see any options. I tried to get the directive files from Source Control, but still not working for me. I guess I'll try re-starting my laptop and getting them again from TFS.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is correct that disable when item.hidden is true but you don't need ng-disabled directive in ng-options

Comment: Can you provide a plunker/fiddle?

Comment: I found that they are not working correctly in that area at all. Most likely it's not the disable thing I tried to add but rather something else I'm still trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

I believe my syntax is fine. I was having a different problem yesterday with our directive. Apparently it needs to have its data in advance, there is some sort of a race conditions (as my colleague explains). When I have the data created before that directive was activated, then it worked just fine.